# How can I deliver a HTML form created by Django or DRF to React?

Tags: json, django, reactjs, django-rest-framework

I'm using React, Django, and DRF.

I wanna send a form consisting of HTML that is auto-generated in Django to React in JSON.

Below is a simple example.

```
[
    {
        "html": "<tr><th><label for="id_writer">Writer:</label></th><td><input type="text" name="writer" maxlength="20" required id="id_writer"></td></tr>"
    }
]
```

I've seen a few times recommending Django as an just JSON API server.

But Django forms are really convenient so I wanna make the most of it.

So I have a few questions I'd like to ask you about.

1. Is this possible?
2. If possible, do you think this is a proper way? I mean, in terms of the philosophy of each framework and library.

Comment: good start: https://medium.com/meural-product-development/setting-up-server-side-rendering-with-react-redux-and-django-4d6f4d2fd705

Comment: Rendering a string of HTML within a React app is not considered a good idea.